# How to embed all fonts from other PDF iText 7

Tags: c#, pdf, fonts, pdf-generation, itext7

I am trying to overlay two PDF files using iText7/C#.
The first one is kind of background and the second one is containing form fields.
Everything works fine and only problem is that I lose fonts from the second file.

I try as follows:

```
static public bool Overlay(string back_path, string front_path, string merge_path)
{
    PdfReader reader;
    PdfDocument pdf = null, front;
    try
    {
        reader = new PdfReader(back_path);
        pdf = new PdfDocument(reader, new PdfWriter(merge_path));
        front = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(front_path));

        var form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(front, false);
        PdfAcroForm dform = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdf, true);
        IDictionary<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.GetFormFields();

        // copy styles
        dform.SetDefaultResources(form.GetDefaultResources());
        dform.SetDefaultAppearance(form.GetDefaultAppearance().GetValue());

        // do overlay
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, PdfFormField> pair in fields)
        {
            try
            {
                var field = pair.Value;
                PdfPage page = field.GetWidgets().First().GetPage();

                int pg_no = front.GetPageNumber(page);
                if (pg_no < front_start_page || pg_no > front_end_page)
                    continue;
                PdfObject copied = field.GetPdfObject().CopyTo(pdf, true);
                PdfFormField copiedField = PdfFormField.MakeFormField(copied, pdf);

                // The following returns null. If it returns something, I think I could use copiedField.setFont(font). 
                // var font = field.GetFont(); 

                dform.AddField(copiedField, pdf.GetPage(pg_no));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Overlaying field {pair.Key} failed. ({ex.Message})");
            }
        }

        pdf.Close();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new OverlayException(ex.Message);
    }
}

public static PdfDictionary get_font_dict(PdfDocument pdfDoc)
{
    PdfDictionary acroForm = pdfDoc.GetCatalog().GetPdfObject().GetAsDictionary(PdfName.AcroForm);
    if (acroForm == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    PdfDictionary dr = acroForm.GetAsDictionary(PdfName.DR);
    if (dr == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    PdfDictionary font = dr.GetAsDictionary(PdfName.Font);
    return font;
}
```

So basically I get all fonts from the second PDF and copy them to the final PDF.
But it does not work.

Logically, I think setting font of the original field to the copied one is the right way.
I mean PdfFormField.GetFont() and SetFont(). 
But it always returns null.

Comment: Copying just PDF objects is not enough. You also have to reference them properly, which does not happen automatically. Show us your way of merging files and if possible example PDFs to reproduce the issue

Comment: Hi, Alexey. Thanks for your reply. Please check the edit. I added as much as I can. Sorry, I can't add the example PDFs. Looking forward to your answer.

Comment: Does the background PDF contain any form fields or other annotations? If it does not, the most simple way to solve your issue is to add the background to the form field PDF instead of adding the form fields and global AcroForm information to the background PDF. Furthermore, does the form PDF contain any static content?

Comment: Thanks, @mkl. I'll try your suggestion. For your information, the background PDF can be assumed not to have form fields or annotations. I mean we can assume background PDF only contains static content (scanned form) and the front PDF only contains formfields. What I'm most curious on is why field.GetFont() returns null. If not, it seems to be straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment you clarified:

> the background PDF can be assumed not to have form fields or annotations. I mean we can assume background PDF only contains static content (scanned form) and the front PDF only contains formfields.

In that case the easiest way to implement your method is to add the background as xobject to the form PDF instead of adding the form to the background PDF.

You can simply do that like this:

```
PdfReader formReader = new PdfReader(front_path);
PdfReader backReader = new PdfReader(back_path);
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(merge_path);

using (PdfDocument source = new PdfDocument(backReader))
using (PdfDocument target = new PdfDocument(formReader, writer))
{
    PdfFormXObject xobject = source.GetPage(1).CopyAsFormXObject(target);
    PdfPage targetFirstPage = target.GetFirstPage();
    PdfStream stream = targetFirstPage.NewContentStreamBefore();
    PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(stream, targetFirstPage.GetResources(), target);
    Rectangle cropBox = targetFirstPage.GetCropBox();
    pdfCanvas.AddXObject(xobject, cropBox.GetX(), cropBox.GetY());
}
```

Depending on the exact static contents of the background and the form PDF, you might want to use `NewContentStreamAfter` instead of `NewContentStreamBefore` or even to use some nifty blend mode to get the exact static content look you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I succeeded to resolve my problems. The only side effect is that I had to insert some pages from background to the target pdf. (I didn't mentioned to make the problem simple, but there are page range parameters that should be considered) Although I still want kind of normal and descent way (copying fields and placing them), I have to mark your answer as accepted. Thanks again.

Comment: *"I still want kind of normal and descent way (copying fields and placing them)"* - I'm afraid that is more complex in general than one would like because of possible collisions - there might already be fonts with the same name in the source PDF and in the target PDF default form resources - requiring a rewrite of some form field properties.

Comment: It's reasonable. @mkl. Thanks again!